# In case of usage ui-view, angular calls controller several times

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-routing

I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong in ui-view configuration. As most of the answers what I see by this post is that controller is defined in router and html.

Please have a look at this example, it calls controller 11 times! (Click about and check table: there are 11 rows with "hi")

http://plnkr.co/edit/YOshrVFmtUHFEvhdWH6S?p=preview

```
routerApp.controller('scotchController', function($scope) {

  $scope.message = 'test';

  $scope.hi = function() {
    $scope.scotches.push({name: 'hi', price: 10})   
  };
```

Your ideas how to fix and make only one call to controller are welcome!

Comment: My bet is that you are calling "hi()" function within the table template. I think that when you call "hi()" function it causes to table template re-rendering. When the template is re-renders it calls "hi()" once again and it causes to another re-render cycle. You should look at console errors, you are entering to infinite loop.

Comment: Fair enough, but why is re-rendering happen in such case? It means that is not possible to call functions inside of templates, as well as filters, cause initially my issue started with filter and I started to simplify my code, and one way which I found how to avoid this problem - move filter from html to controller.

Comment: I'm not sure that filtering should cause the same effect, if you'll provide  a Plunker with your initial problem, the reason can be different.

Comment: Ok no problem, did it: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPkkQ7uIbmTvs9sLoP6r?p=preview I applied the filter to array in ng-repeat. You can find it in table-data.html. So the idea to split array to sub-arrays and then display them in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is the culprit. While it returns an object with the same values, it returns a different object every iteration, meaning that the model is modified. If you look at the console you'll see that Angular eventually gives up and that you have an [infinite digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:16,%22oldVal%22:14%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Macallan%2012%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:50%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Chivas%20Regal%20Royal%20Salute%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:10000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Glenfiddich%201937%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:20000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:18,%22oldVal%22:16%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Macallan%2012%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:50%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Chivas%20Regal%20Royal%20Salute%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:10000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Glenfiddich%201937%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:20000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:20,%22oldVal%22:18%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Macallan%2012%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:50%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Chivas%20Regal%20Royal%20Salute%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:10000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Glenfiddich%201937%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:20000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:22,%22oldVal%22:20%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Macallan%2012%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:50%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Chivas%20Regal%20Royal%20Salute%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:10000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Glenfiddich%201937%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:20000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:24,%22oldVal%22:22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Macallan%2012%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:50%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Chivas%20Regal%20Royal%20Salute%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:10000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22Glenfiddich%201937%5C%22,%5C%22price%5C%22:20000%7D%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,%5Cnc,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22%22%7D%5D%5D).

I typically use filters for display formatting purposes only. IMO this kind of data transforming belongs in your controller. If it needs to be shared across multiple controllers move the code into a factory or service and your controllers can use that.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I saw the error in the console, I just didn't get why Angular behaviour like this. In this case filter functionality inside of ui-view is quite limited

Comment: If your filter return the *same exact* object and not an object that just happened to look the same the errors should go away. I just don't think a filter is the right choice here.

Comment: I meant that before your first explanation it was not completely clear. Thanks for the answer!